# NDB Modeling One-to-one with KeyProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, database-design, app-engine-ndb

I'm quite new to ndb but I've already understood that I need to rewire a certain area in my brain to create models. I'm trying to create a simple model - just for the sake of understanding how to design an ndb database - with a one-to-one relationship: for instance, a user and his info. After searching around a lot - found documentation but it was hard to find different examples - and experimenting a bit (modeling and querying in a couple of different ways), this is the solution I found:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Monster(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def get_by_name(cls, name):
        return cls.query(cls.name == name).get()

    def get_info(self):
        return Info.query(Info.monster == self.key).get()

class Info(ndb.Model):
    monster = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Monster')
    address = ndb.StringProperty()

a = Monster(name = "Dracula")
a.put()

b = Info(monster = a.key, address = "Transilvania")
b.put()

print Monster.get_by_name("Dracula").get_info().address
```

NDB doesn't accept joins, so the "join" we want has to be emulated using class methods and properties. With the above system I can easily reach a property in the second database (Info) through a unique property in the first (in this case "name" - suppose there are no two monsters with the same name).

However, if I want to print a list with 100 monster names and respective addresses, the second database (Info) will be hit 100 times.

Question: is there a better way to model this to increase performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its truly a one to one relationship, why are creating 2 models.  Given your example the Address entity cannot be shared with any Monster so why not put the Address details in the monster.

There are some reasons why you wouldn't.

1. Address could become large and therefore less efficient to retrieve 100's of properties when you only need a couple - though project queries may help there.
2. You change your mind and you want to see all monsters that live in Transylvania - in which case you would create the address entity and the Monster would have the key property that points to the Address.  This obviously fails when you work out that some monsters can live in multiple places (Werewolfs - London, Transylvania, New York ;-)  , in which case you either have a repeating KeyProperty in the monstor or an intermediate entity that points to the monster and the address.  In your case I don't think that monsters on the whole have that many documented Addresses ;-)

Also if you are uniquely identifying monsters by name you should consider storing the name as part of the key.  Doing a Monster.get_by_id("dracula") is quicker than a query by name.

As I wrote (poorly) in the comment. If 1. above holds and it is a true one to one relationship.  I would then create Address as a child entity (Monster is the parent/ancestor in the key) when creating address.  This allows you to,

1. allow other entities to point to the Address,
2. If you create a bunch of child entities, fetch them with a single
   ancestor query).  3 If you have get monster and it's owned entities
   again it's an ancestor query.
3. If you have a bunch of entities that
   should only exist if Monster instance exists and they are not
   children, then you have to do querys on all the entity types with
   KeyProperty's matching the key, and if theses entities are not
   PolyModels, then you have to perform a query for each entity
   type (and know you need to perform the query on a given entity,
   which involves a registry of some type, or hard coding things)

Comment: '@Tim' thanks for the answer. Reason 1 is the correct one. Info will become large, I'll add many other properties, like monster's city, country, phone number, etc, and I don't need them every time I query Monster. And I will link other model's to them, with info like last_appearance, eat_people (boolean). I'm not storing the name as part of the key because I want to be able to change it (like username in some websites). However, I can also just add the rule that the 'name' property cannot be changed and has to be unique.

Comment: ok, given this I would make the address a child entity (specify monster is the parent when constructing, probably with a known key name). It has know business existing with out the monster, other entities can reference it directly.  THe could be a whole bunch of child entities, that you could then fetch with a single ancestor query.

Comment: Ok Tim, great! As I am new to ndb and the documentation lacks in practical examples, would you be so kind to show me the code? I have been playing with child/parent relationships in the Interactive Console, but I got nowhere, I don't understand very well how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you may be trying could be achieved by using elements described in the link below 
Have a look at "Operations on Multiple Keys or Entities" "Expando Models" "Model Hooks"

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities

(This is probably more a comment than an answer)

Comment: Ok, so I have a one-to-one relationship and I want to retrieve a list with properties from both models. What would be the best pattern for that? There are many ways to do that, Tim (above) already said that using ID to retrieve an entity is faster than querying. You see, what I miss is a ndb documentation with common patterns.